# laravel : how to by pass throttle middleware for some routes in

Tags: laravel, throttling, laravel-middleware

[image]

in my Laravel project
These two queries are executing everywhere regarding my route's middleware I need to skip them for some routes how can I do that

I have tried creating "withoutThrottle" middleware in the kernel like this

[image]

but it's not working

Comment: Please avoid posting images of code/error. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can skip routes by grouping them in your `api.php`, for example:

```php
Route::wihtouMiddleware(['throttle:api'])->group(function () {
    Route::post('/x', function () {
        // ...
    });
 
    Route::post('/y', function () {
        // ...
    });
});
```

Or Single Routes:

```php
Route::post('/x', function () {
 // ...
})->wihtouMiddleware(['throttle:api']);
```